# Including external script in vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and web-pack, so I decided to use the vue-cli (webpack) to scaffold an initial application. I'm trying to include an external script (e.g `<script src="..."`) in a template which isn't needed globally (for every page/component), however Vue warns that this isn't allowed.

My index.html file is similar to the initial generated one:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>App</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My App.vue is also similar to the generated one:

```
<template>
<div id="app">

  <div class="container pt-5">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

I have a route to `/upload` in my routes file, which maps to an Upload component which requires dropzone.js (an external script). I could include it in my index.html, similarly to how bootstrap is loaded, however it seems less than ideal to load it for every page/component when only this component requires it.

However, as stated above, I simply cannon include it in my template file as such:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h2>Upload Images</h2>
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
      <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://example.com/path/to/dropzone"></script>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>

<style>  
</style>
```

How can I include an external script for only one component?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a method that will be responsible for script loading and call it in the mounted or created hook like below:

```
<script>
      export default {
        data() {
          return {}
        },
        methods: {
          loadJs(url, callback) {
            jQuery.ajax({
              url: url,
              dataType: 'script',
              success: callback,
              async: true
            });
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.loadJs('url_to_someScript.js', function() {
            //Stuff to do after someScript has loaded
          });
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: please try this and tell me if it's working for you.

Comment: It works but `method` should be `methods`. I tried to edit it but it won't let you save unless you change a minimum of 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Script tags are global by nature. Including scripts tag in template is not how you do with modules systems (at least for now).

You can install it as a node module using npm, `npm install dropzone --save`.

Then import it inside your component code.

```
import drozone from 'dropzone';
export default {
  // Component code...
}
```

However, be aware that the bundle will contain dropzone in every page, unless you are using webpack code splitting feature. See [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) for an official tutorial about how to split your bundle with Vue Router.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to only load the resource as the template is rendered (without code splitting with webpack)

Comment: @AshleyB No, you should use webpack dynamic import feature for that.

Comment: That requires dropzone installed locally though, is there not any way of using it as an external resource?

Comment: @AshleyB As far as I know, no.