# script src with vue.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to put my vue code into an external .js file. I'm using it the simple way without webpack, because I'm just starting with vue.
The problem is that vue doesn't work if you use script src as the html tag.
For example:
this is my test.html with following code:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
<script src="myvuefile.js"></script>
```

and this is my vue file:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
});
```

If I put it directly in my html file it works, but I want to use a seperate js file. How is this possible?

Best regards

Comment: You have to use the methode ike here :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145448/including-external-script-in-vue-js-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145448/including-external-script-in-vue-js-template)

Answer (score 0):

It is something like that :

```
   document.addEventListener('load', function() {
   var app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
         data: {
         message: 'Hello Vue!'
          },
         methods: {
           loadJs(url, callback) {
             jQuery.ajax({
               url: url,
               dataType: 'script',
               success: callback,
               async: true
             });
           }
         },
         mounted() {
           this.loadJs('myvuefile.js', 
        function() {
             //Stuff to do after someScript has loaded
           });
```